# Changed laravel folder and remove folder now route is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

My current folder structure of laravel project is

```
local
---app
---bootstrap
---vender
index.php
.htaccess
```

Its my route.php inside app folder

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.home');
});
Route::get('about', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.about');
});
Route::get('projects', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.projects');
});
Route::get('contact', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.contact');
});
```

It's my .htacess file in root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My main project is located at localhost/laravel. It display all the menu proper but

When i am click on about menu or other menu project redirect to localhost/project or localhost/about.
and its worked by type manually url like localhost/laravel/project or localhost/laravel/about etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ laravel/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. 
`<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/projects">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>        
      </ul>`
I am using that from changing the page. if i remove /(slash) from prefix its work but in live server not working

Comment: Is the live server using apache or nginx ?

Comment: apache server. i found little solution. I have running apache in window panel some time .htaccess not work so i have to use web.config file